# Convert JSON Data to NSString JSON Serialization in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization

I want to convert json string (or) Json data to NSDictionary (or) NSArray, its coming nil value. But data is coming in NSString and NSData? Please, help me on this issue?

```
 [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if(!error){
NSString *requestReply1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *objectData = [requestReply1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];            
NSLog(@"response=%@", jsonDict);
}
 }] resume];
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the meaning between the conversions `requestReply1` and `objectData`? Also, you did `error:&error` do you mind checking if it's nil or not, and print it? if you print `requestReply1`, what's the value?

Comment: @Larme requestReply1 is Json String from server data i saved. 
ObjectData is i converted Json string data.
If i print requestReply1 string its coming, but after convert NSDictionary shows Nil.

Comment: Again, what's the value of `error`? If you copy/paste your `requestReply1`  into an only JSON validator, is it valid? Also, I meant that in `NSString *requestReply1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *objectData = [requestReply1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`, `objectData` is equals to `data` the the conversion seems not useful.

Comment: @Larme ya i checked it's valid Json. Ok then, how i need to convert JSON String to NSDictionary (or) NSArray?

Comment: if `jsonDict` is nil, could you for the third time print the `error`? that you put in parameter of the NSJONSeralization method?

Comment: @Larme i updated my Code Check it. I checked with error not null i will do JSON Serialization?

Comment: Do NSError *jsonError = nil; NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError]; if (jsonError){ NSLog("jsonError: %@", jsonError);} else {NSLog(@"response=%@", jsonDict);}

Comment: @Larme i got this error: 

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 212." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 212.}

Comment: Now we are talking. It seems that the iOS parser doesn't like the character at index 212. Now, do you mind giving the full JSON? Or at least do `NSString *substring = [requestReply1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(212-10, 10)]` and print its value? If it's possible (maybe the range is too big, change it if you get an out of range crash error) or augmente it if it doesn't show useful info. And if possible give also the full error (you can put "..." at private values to anomyze it)